# How can i returns the number of matches rather than printing the matches?

Tags: linux, command-line

How can I return the number of matches rather than printing the matches? So basically what command should I use?

Comment: Please edit your question and give us an example of the command you're running. In general, to count the number of lines in an output, pipe it through `wc -l`.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Since answers can vary substantially depending on the use case, please try to be more specific and edit your answer to include sample input and expected output. One important question is whether multiple matches can occur on the same line.

Comment: The question lacks information about what you want the number of matches _from_, i.e. whether it's a `grep` command, some `curl` query against a REST API, or something completely different.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using grep, use a combination of `-o` (makes grep print each match) and `wc -l`:

Test file:

```
aaa bbb ccc aaa ddd eee
fff aaa ggg hhh aaa jjj
```

Execution:

```
>grep -o aaa foo.dat| wc -l
4
```

Comment: please don't answer question is unclear, could be about find or anything else. besides grep -oc is the correct answer

Comment: No, `grep -oc` returns `2` and not `4` with the example above.

Comment: oh noooo! i have to rewrite all my scripts